# BibTex not working with TexShop when changing from version 2.43 to 3.51

Tags: bibtex, texshop

I am trying to write a document in Latex (TexShop 3.51) in my MacOs with the following format:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[papersize={16.8cm,24cm},width=120mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\bibliography{Biblio.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
citecolor=red}

\title{Bla Bla Bla}
\author{Bla Bla}
\date{24$^{th}$ of November of 2015}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
Bla bla bla \cite{Baibich_PRL88}

\section*{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

When I compile this .tex file, later I try to compile my Biblio.bib file, which is the following:

```
@article{Baibich_PRL88,
  title={Giant magnetoresistance of (001) Fe/(001) Cr magnetic superlattices},
  author={Baibich, Mario Norberto and Broto, Jean Marc and Fert, Albert and Van Dau, F Nguyen and Petroff, Fr{\'e}d{\'e}ric and Etienne, P and Creuzet, G and Friederich, A and Chazelas, J},
  journal={Physical review letters},
  volume={61},
  number={21},
  pages={2472},
  year={1988},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

And I obtain the following message:

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Main.aux

I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Main.aux

I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Main.aux
```

And when I check my Main.aux file, it does not contain any of the information required by the bibtex:

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\abx@aux@sortscheme{nty}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\@writefile{toc}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lof}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lot}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\abx@aux@cite{Baibich_PRL88}
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{iv}{chapter.1}}
\@writefile{lof}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
```

The curious thing is that exactly the same files are working properly in my older TexShop version, 2.43 (i.e., the .aux contains the \bibstyle, \bibdata and \citation informations). If I try to use in the newest TexShop application the .aux file that the compilation of the .tex file generates with version 2.43, then it tells me there is an incompatibility of versions. Also, If I insert the bibliography at the end of my .tex file as \begin{thebibliography} + \bibtem in version 3.51, then it is fine. But I really need bibtex to be working because it is going to be a long document.

I would really appreciate some help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are not suppose to be using `biber` not `bibtex`?

Answer (score 1):

Independent from your used editor TeXShop and its version the relevant line in your code for your problem is this one:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

That means that `biblatex` is adviced to use `biber` as backend.  To document this (I strongly recommend to do this always!) you can also write:

```
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
```

If you really want to use `bibtex` you can change `backend=biber` to `backend=bibtex`.  But better is to learn how you can advice TeXShop to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`.  Because I do not have a MAC I can not help you there ...

Following your description in your question I think that one editor calls `biber` the other `bibtex` and that causes your resulting error.

With the following MWE (for `biber`, just change it to `bibtex` if needed, see marking comment `<==========`)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Baibich_PRL88,
  title     = {Giant magnetoresistance of (001) Fe/(001) Cr magnetic 
               superlattices},
  author    = {Baibich, Mario Norberto and Broto, Jean Marc and 
               Fert, Albert and Van Dau, F Nguyen and 
               Petroff, Fr{\'e}d{\'e}ric and Etienne, P and Creuzet, G 
               and Friederich, A and Chazelas, J},
  journal   = {Physical review letters},
  volume    = {61},
  number    = {21},
  pages     = {2472},
  year      = {1988},
  publisher = {APS},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[papersize={16.8cm,24cm},width=120mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber % bibtex % <==============================================
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib} % <== to call bibfile created with filecontents

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=black,
  urlcolor=black,
  citecolor=red
}

\title{Bla Bla Bla}
\author{Bla Bla}
\date{24$^{th}$ of November of 2015}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
Bla bla bla \cite{Baibich_PRL88}

\section*{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

with the resulting third page:

[image: resulting third page]

You can test this also with commands in your terminal.  Lets say you copied my MWE with the the name `mwe.tex`.  Then you can type the commands

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

to create the file needed for `bibtex`/`biber`: `mwe.aux`. Then  with backend `biber`:

```
biber mwe
```

or with backend `bibtex`:

```
bibtex mwe
```

and then two times

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how olde your previous versions of biblatex and biber are but recent versions use the biber program instead of bibtex to process the .bib file.

Place the line

% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk

at the top of your file. Then typeset using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T) and the pdflatexmk engine (which uses pdflatex and the latexmk perl script). The latexmk perl script will do all the necessary processing for you as well as use biber or bibtex, whichever is necessary, to do the bibliography processing.

PS: it has nothing to do with TeXShop.